# Why don't I have to add 'python' before invoking Python script?

Tags: python

I am new to programming, and Python is my first language.
I've added Python to my Path, but when I use the Command Prompt, I don't have to add python before *myscript.py* as opposed to many tutorials I've seen. Here is an example:

```
C:\User\MyName>Welcome.py
Welcome to Python
Python is fun
```

When I enter 'python', there is a subsequent error:

```
C:\User\MyName>python Welcome.py
python: can't open file 'Welcome.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Do I really need the 'python'?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this happen for any `.py` file you have, or just `Welcome.py`? (I've got a hunch...)

Comment: This has happened to all .py files I have

Comment: What does `assoc .py` show when run in the command prompt?

Comment: When I enter assoc.py? it says File association not found for extension .py I might have screwed something up... :(

Comment: What version of Windows are you running and what is the content of Welcome.py?

Comment: I am running Windows 7

Comment: Can you also check which Welcome.py you are calling (type `>where Welcome.py`)? Then can you confirm what Welcome.py contains? Does it really just contain two python print statements (or is it a windows script in disguise)?

Comment: @JonClements That doesn't work for OP because `.py` isn't in `PATHEXT` apparently! I'm having all these flashbacks to Python development on Windows now... All I can see are bright orange keywords!!

Comment: @2rs2ts I have Python installed on a fresh Windows7 VM and `>assoc .py ` returns `.py=Python.File`

Comment: @RiazRizvi All right, maybe my hunch is off.

Answer (score 4):

If you followed the [Python on Windows FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows), it seems that the standard Python installer has already taken the liberty of [associating `.py` files](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable) with an open command to `..\..\Python\python.exe "%1" %*`.

> How do I make Python scripts executable?
>
> On Windows, the standard Python installer already associates the .py extension with a file type (Python.File) and gives that file type an open command that runs the interpreter (D:\Program Files\Python\python.exe "%1" %*). This is enough to make scripts executable from the command prompt as ‘foo.py’. If you’d rather be able to execute the script by simple typing ‘foo’ with no extension you need to add .py to the PATHEXT environment variable.

Who'd have thunk! This isn't the way it used to be four years ago when I first installed Python on my Windows machine.

Comment: apparently the action to execute `.py` scripts is set in the Windows Registry by the installer. This comment put me on the way to resolving broken execution of `script.py` scripts without writing `python script.py`. Searching for ".py" in the registry led me to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py_auto_file\shell\open\command\Default` which had to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.
It really depends on how the script is written.

On most unix systems (Linux, Mac OS), you could include `#!/bin/python` to the top of (as the first line of) your script and therefore execute it by just calling the filename on the command line. That first line tells the shell that this file contains a python program. The shell then uses the python interpreter to execute the file (translation: it translates your `$ Welcome.py` to `$ /bin/python Welcome.py` <- note that python is being called explicitly and that it's the same path as what's on the first line of your file).

Presumably, the Windows OS can also be instructed in the same way, though I have never been able to do it myself, nor have I tried very hard (I moved away from windows about 5 years ago). This is why you'll need to explicitly call `python`.
Calling python tells the OS: "hey! open that program called python and tell it to run the file `Welcome.py`". This is exactly what the command `/bin/python Welcome.py` does on a unix system

Comment: @RiazRizvi: granted. Which is why I was skeptical about posting this in the first place. But then I thought that it's valid information, and provides some insight into what's going on. I was also hoping that someone who knows more than I do would splice in the part that I missed. I posted this not for the rep, but for the info to be out there. Please let me know if you think it shouldn't be here (and if that's a popular opinion) and, I'll delete it

Comment: In Windows, I think you have to add `python.exe` (typically in `C:\Python33` or something like that) to `PATH` to achieve the same.

Comment: the  error only occurs when explicitly calling though.  I think you're answering the opposite question.

Answer (score 1):

When you install python on windows with a regular installer, .py files are associated with the python.exe you installed. When you type `Welcome.py`, Windows searches the local directory and then all paths in the PATH variable for a program called Welcome.py and runs it via python. Since this worked for you, it means that Welcome.py is somewhere on your path or in your local directory.

You can figure out your file associations with the `assoc .py` and `ftype Python.File` commands. The `echo %PATH%` and `echo %PATHEXT%` commands are also useful.

When you type `python Welcome.py`, Windows searches all paths in the PATH variable for a program that starts with 'python' and ends with an extension in PATHEXT. It finds 'python.exe' and runs it. Python in turn looks for a script called Welcome.py in the current directory. Since this didn't work for you, it means that Welcome.py is not in your local directory. It would have worked if you had given the right path to Welcome.py.

You can find out where Welcome.py is with the (not surprisingly) `where Welcome.py` command.

If you only have a single python installation, there is no need to call `python myscript.py ...`.